# Replace WSUS with cloud serverless solution - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server, windows-update, aws-ssm

We are using WSUS (Windows Server Update Services) for updating employees computers (laptops/desktops running on Win10/11), currently WSUS is running on an EC2 instance in AWS.

**Our goal is to get rid of WSUS EC2 instance and use some cloud based solution** instead, preferably serverless running on AWS, could you please recommend us some solution which would suit our requirements?

Our first idea was to use AWS SSM but with SSM you are able to manage only Windows Server instances but you cannot manage personal computers running on Windows10&11.

Comment: By client devices, do you mean that they're still on EC2?

Comment: By client devices I mean employees personal computers (laptops or desktops), they are not on EC2, for this case only WSUS is EC2. I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using [Amazon WorkSpaces](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/) for your device provisioning or [AWS IoT Device Management](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-device-management/) for IoT devices, there is no MDM (Mobile Device Management) service offered by AWS for Windows machines.